# How to hide year toggle from header in mat-datepicker

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular8, mat-datepicker

[image]

```
.mat-calendar-period-button{
min-width: 0;
display: none !important; 
}

button.mat-calendar-period-button.mat-button.mat-button-base {
display: none !important;
}

button:not(:disabled), [type="button"]:not(:disabled), [type="reset"]:not(:disabled),  
[type="submit"]:not(:disabled) {
cursor: pointer;
display: none !important;
}
```

I used this CSS but it didn't work.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have standard [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation), you need to add [`::ng-deep`](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) to styles which are inside a component you are using. Try this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-calendar-period-button{
  display: none; 
}
```